# How to open textarea in new window?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have, it's not working. please help.

```
var myWindow = window.open("","","width=600,height=450");
newContent = myWindow.document.createElement("textarea");
myWindow.document.appendChild(newContent);
```

Comment: not working HOW? did you check your javascript console for errors?

Comment: Might be popup blocker issue?

Comment: Not a pop-up blocker issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myWindow = window.open("","","width=600,height=450");
newContent = myWindow.document.createElement("textarea");
 myWindow.document.appendChild(newContent);
```

Send an error :

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
>   'Node': Nodes of type 'INPUT' may not be inserted inside nodes of type
>   '#document'.

So just change

```
 myWindow.document.appendChild(newContent);
```

To

```
 myWindow.document.body.appendChild(newContent);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hjUrP/

Comment: Can I resize this textarea and window according to content ?

Comment: Can you explain a little more ? Or better, can you ask new question and link it in comment please ? It can interrest other user.

Answer (score 2):

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3fb2Q/5/)

```
function openWin(){
    var myWindow = window.open("","","width=600,height=450");
    myWindow.document.write("<textarea rows='30' cols='70'></textarea>");
}
```